# Чи правильно вживати "Невід'ємне право"?

Tags: росіянізм, прикметники, калька

В різних джерелах зустрічаються різні варіанти. Чому "невід'ємне право" не бажано вживати?

[Onlinecorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/)

> Замініть прикметник *невід’ємний*, що має ознаки кальки, на стилістично кращий варіант за контекстом: невіддільний, неодмінний, невідчужуваний (невідчужний), невідокремний.
>
> НЕ РЕКОМЕНДОВАНО  *невід’ємне право*
>
> РЕКОМЕНДОВАНО *невідчужуване право*

[Конституція України](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/254%D0%BA/96-%D0%B2%D1%80)

> Стаття 27. Кожна людина має *невід'ємне право* на життя.

Answer (score 5):

Online Corrector рекомендує використовувати слово *"невідчужуваний"*, бо *"відчужувати"* - `юридичний термін`. [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=14317&page=462:):

> **ВІДЧУ́ЖУВАТИ**, ую, уєш, недок., **ВІДЧУ́ЖИТИ**, жу, жиш, док.
>
> 2. що, *юр.* Спираючись на певний закон, відбирати в кого-небудь майно на користь держави, організації чи окремої особи.
>
> Кожний громадянин .. має право .. набувати і відчужувати майно із зазначеними в законі обмеженнями (з мови документів); – Спасибі, таки відчужили хоч хату та кузню, мене наділили (А. Головко).

На [цій](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/435-15/page8) сторінці Цивільного кодексу України можна знайти достатньо прикладів використання *"відчужувати"* та похідних слів.

Можливо автори хотіли наголосити на повсякденності цього права, а не тільки у рамках законів.
Висновок: *"відчужувати"* рекомендується використовувати в юридичному контексті, [*"невід'ємний"*](http://sum.in.ua/s/nevid.jemnyj) - у значенні того, кого не можна відокремити від когось чи чогось, у повсякденному контексті.